# Socket keep returning double string value

Tags: python, sockets, networking

So i made a simple server-client with socket in python and i have this problem is that the server keep returning double of the string from client can anyone help me? thanks.

Server:

```
def new_user(client,addr):

    while True:
        data = client.recv(10030)
        client.settimeout(5.0)
        if not data:
            break
        if data == ("-quit-"):
            break
        data = data.upper()
        print("Client ->",data)
        data = raw_input("Admin ->")
        client.send(data)
    client.close()

def main():

    start_user()

def start_user():

    s = socket.socket()
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET,socket.SO_REUSEADDR,1)
    print("Socket Telah Dibuat")
    try:
        s.bind(('',4303))
        print("Bind telah dibuat")
    except:
        print("Bind failed"+str(sys.exc_info()))
        sys.exit(1)
    s.listen(1)
    while True:
        client , addr = s.accept()
        print("Client telah connect:"+str(addr))
        Thread(target=new_user,args=(client,addr)).start()
    s.close()
```

Client:

```
def main():

    s = socket.socket()
    print("Socket Telah Dibuat")
    try:
        s.connect(('',4303))
        print("telah connect")
    except:
        print("connection failed"+str(sys.exc_info()))
        sys.exit(1)
    print("Untuk Quit Masukkan--quit--:")
    message = raw_input("->")
    while message != ("--quit--"):
        s.send(message)
        data = s.recv(10030)
        if not data:
            break
        data = data.upper()
        print("Admin ->",data)
        message = raw_input("->")
        s.send(message)
    s.close()
```

## server run

```
('Client ->', 'HELLO')-- from here
Admin ->yes 
('Client ->', 'WHAT UP')
Admin ->yo too
('Client ->', 'WHAT UP')
Admin ->what -- to here is still working
('Client ->', 'LETS MEET UPLETS MEET UP') <--this where its start to get error
```

## client run

```
Socket Telah Dibuat
telah connect
Untuk Quit Masukkan--quit--:
->hello
('Admin ->', 'YES')
->what up
('Admin ->', 'YO TOO')
->lets meet up
('Admin ->', 'WHAT ')
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The client is sending the message twice.:

```
while message != ("--quit--"):
    s.send(message)  // HERE
    data = s.recv(10030)
    if not data:
        break
    data = data.upper()
    print("Admin ->",data)
    message = raw_input("->")
    s.send(message) // AND HERE
```

Answer (score 2):

May be you can change to:

```
message = ""    
while message != ("--quit--"):
    message = raw_input("->")
    s.send(message)
    data = s.recv(10030)
    if not data:
        break
    data = data.upper()
    print("Admin ->",data)
```